# Как подключить ulogin на kohana

Tags: ulogin, kohana

Никак не могу понять как подключить ulogin, в README пишет:

```
 1. Создать таблицу ulogins:
CREATE TABLE `ulogins` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `network` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `identity` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `identity` (`identity`)
)
 2. Добавить 'ulogins' => array(), в protected $_has_many у модели user
```

таблицу создал, а вот второй пункт никак не могу понять, модель user сам создаешь? подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model_User` уже есть, если подключить модули `Auth` и `ORM`.
См. [`modules/orm/classes/Model/User.php`](https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.3/master/classes/Model/User.php)

Comment: @xEdelweiss, чтоб ввести изменения в моделе user не нужно ее клонировать в aplication?

Comment: Только тот файл, на который я дал ссылку

Comment: @xEdelweiss,аха, спасибо, понял, еще один вопрос: смотрю модели ulogin ни в одном не вижу соединения и сохранения нового пользователя в таблицу ulogins, это тоже сам делаешь да?

Comment: @bemulima, я не работал с модулем ``ulogins``. Но есть же там метод [``create_new_user()``](https://github.com/ulogin/ulogin-Kohana/blob/master/classes/Kohana/Ulogin.php#L166) и [``create_ulogin()``](https://github.com/ulogin/ulogin-Kohana/blob/master/classes/Kohana/Ulogin.php#L157)

Comment: @xEdelweiss, ))) в упор не вижу эти методы

Comment: @bemulima, даже с учётом того, что я дал ссылки?)

Comment: @xEdelweiss, всё нашел, спасибо за помощь!